# How to read const &vector<Mat> data type from EM::getCov(&vector<Mat>) for c++

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, expectation-maximization

I am trying to get the result of this function:

**C++:**

```
void EM::getCovs(std::vector<Mat>& covs) const
```

My question is how to get the `covs`? I kept getting compiling error. Here is my code.

```
const vector<Mat> &covs;
model->getCovs(covs);
```

I get error said

> Declaration of reference variable 'covs' requires an initializer.

(1) This is the correct way to get data from getCovs, or

(2) I need to initialize 'covs' like the error showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&` in the parameter list `void getCovs(std::vector& covs)` means that you *pass a reference* to an existing vector.

You should declare local storage for a vector:

```
vector<Mat> covs;
```

then you can pass a reference to it into `getCovs`:

```
model->getCovs(covs);
```

What you wrote (`vector<Mat>& covs;`) is a local variable that references another vector; however you haven't provided another vector for it to reference. The `const` also prevents it from being modified, but you want it to be modified by the getCovs function.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare it as `vector<Mat> covs;`. You want a real vector, not a reference, to pass to the function. And you don't want it to be const because you want the function to write into it.